# How can you allocate a class in objective-c from NSString object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I've got a PHP background, but I'm beginning to learn Objective-C, so that I can develop apps for the iPhone. So far things are going pretty well, but I've got a question that I haven't been able to find and answer to yet after googling and mining a number of different forums.

My app has to create a number of views, each with it's own uinque title bar. In order to do this, my code looks something like this for each view:

```
    xViewController = [ [ XViewController alloc ] init ];
    xNavController = [ [ UINavigationController alloc ]
        initWithRootViewController: xViewController
    ];
    xNavController.tabBarItem = [ [ UITabBarItem alloc ]
        initWithTitle: @"My Info"
        image: [ UIImage imageNamed: @"my_info.png" ]
        tag: 3
    ];
```

This works, but what I'd like to do is to create a method that will return a nav controller when sent a string as a message, so I don't have to do all this for each view. The issue I am having is that the first line needs to allocate an object based on a class name passed to it as a string (i.e. XViewController needs to be taken from a string passed to the method), but I don't know how to treat a string as a class name. I know it's possible, because the UIApplicationMain() can use a string to call the app delegate class. How can I do it?

I'm sorry if any of this doesn't make sense, I'm still in the early stages of learning a new language!

Comment: You can do this (as the answers below show) but I'm unclear how this would make your code smaller, simpler or less error-prone?

Comment: Why do you have to pass a string as a parameter? Why can’t you pass the Class as a parameter?

Comment: Stephen, it'll do everything you ask about, because I won't have to repeat the code above for each view I create - I can just call a method that does it right every time with one line of code.

Chris, I wasn't aware I could simply pass a class as a parameter, to be honest - but I think this still works better, because I want to use the string for the class name, the 'initWithTitle' method, and the image name.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As well as using the runtime, you can do it just using Cocoa-touch methods:

```
NSString* theClassName = /* assume this exists */
Class theClass = NSClassFromString(theClassName);
NSObject* myObject = [[theClass performSelector:@selector(alloc)] init];
// do something with the new object instance
```

Comment: You don't need the performSelector:, you can just write [[theClass alloc] init].

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple TableViewCells loaded from NIBs, the code to load the individual NIBs gets ugly if you don't do something with dynamic loading.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // header
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cellHeader *cell = (cellHeader *)[self loadCell:identHeader];
        return cell;

    // load more
    } else if (indexPath.row == lastRow) {
        loadMore *cell = (loadMore *)[self loadCell:identLoadMore];
        return cell;
    }

    // default
    cellDefault *cell = (cellDefault *)[self loadCell:identDefault];
    return cell;
}

- (id)loadCell:(NSString *)className {
    id cell = [tweetsView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:className];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:className owner:nil options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
                cell = currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Objective-C 2.0 Runtime Reference](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/class_createInstance)

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your problem correctly you don't need dynamic classes to make this work. Why not create, for each view controller class, its unique `title` and `image` method that just returns the unique title and image for that view controller. Then create a super class for your view controller classes with dummy `title` and `image` methods.

Your code above will then look something like this:

```
- (UINavigationController *)getNavController:(XGenericViewController *)viewController
{
        UINavigationController  *xNavController = [ [ UINavigationController alloc ]
            initWithRootViewController: viewController
        ];
        xNavController.tabBarItem = [ [ UITabBarItem alloc ]
            initWithTitle: [viewController title]
            image: [viewController image]
            tag: 3
        ];

    return [xNavController autorelease];
}
```